# Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem problem

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral

I am having trouble using DCT for the following

Prove 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^\infty \frac{n}{(1+y)^n(ny)^\frac{1}{n}}dy = 1$$

I think most of the mass of the integral lies beneath $(e-1)/n$ but now dont believe this is true, so I was hoping to break up the integral into two parts, but that didn't seem to help. So I seem to be stuck at the moment.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
It would be more helpful to me if you gave me a general suggestion rather than a specific one. Such as how to find the dominating function for integrals which become tidal waves as $n \rightarrow \infty$ or how to chose the point to split the integral into two bits.

Thanks

Comment: This is false, but I assume you mean: the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty.$

Comment: Yes Sorry, that is right, Ill try to correct the equation now.

Answer (score 1):

As I say in the comment, this is false as stated, but I am assuming the OP forgot $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}.$ If so, then for a fixed $n$ this is a standard beta-function integral, which is equal to 
$$\frac{n^{-1/n} \Gamma \left(2-\frac{1}{n}\right) \Gamma
   \left(n-2+\frac{1}{n}\right)}{\Gamma (n).}$$

This, in turn, goes to $0,$ not $1$ as $n$ goes to infinity, so either the claimed answer is wrong, or there is another typo somewhere.

Comment: The gamma function is useful in evaluating the integral, but it does not use DCT.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Igor that the limit is $0$. You can still prove this claim using DCT though. You only need to worry about large values of $n$, so pick $N=3$ say, then when $y>1$ you can bound the function by
$$\frac{y}{(1+y)^{3}}\leq\frac{1}{(1+y)^{2}}$$
which is integrable. On the other hand for $y<1$, you can bound by
$$y^{1-\frac{1}{3}}$$
which is integrable on $[0,1]$. So that piecewise defined function has only one point of discontinuity, hence integrable, and DCT applies. However, if you exchange the limit with the integral you get $0$...not $1$.

Comment: I should say here that for all $n>3$ you have the bounds.

Comment: oh I see, there is $n$ on top, not $y$

Comment: Your Right, I have corrected the equation, the numerator should have been $n$ and not $y$. But thanks for the gamma/beta function suggestion I did not think of that.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{(1+y)^n(ny)^{1/n}}dy = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}  (1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}x^{-\frac{1}{n}}dx
 $$
by substitute $y = \frac{x}{n}$.

Let $f_{n} = (1+\frac{x}{n})^{-n}x^{-\frac{1}{n}}$

Then, by DCT, it is clear that the above integral is $1$.

As a matter of fact, I don't know what is $g$ that dominating $f_{n}$.

I am not sure, but you can use Fatou's lemma for $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ using
$$
\int \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}du \leq  \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_{n}du \leq \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_{n}du \leq \int \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}du
$$

where 
$$
\int \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}du = \int \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_{n}du = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x}dx = 1
$$